# Execute method not blocked in qgis plugin

Tags: python, plugins, background, qgis

I am developing a QGIS Plugins, complex plugin with various classes and methods that call other methods.
My plugin works fine, but I'm loking to run some class method in the background (something like jobs in JAVA) to avoid frozen GUI. I mean, I have a class, this class has a method and this method I would like run in background

I tried with QThread,QTask, threading, QProcess, etc, but I did not find what I want to do.

Some idea could help me? Some plugin does works with background process? Some plugin example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you want to refresh the UI to avoid QGIS freezing.
This is what worked for me:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

QApplication.processEvents()
```

This will refresh the UI of QGIS.
You probably have to call it multiple time, for example after every iteration in a for loop.

Comment: what I would to do is run a method in background without freezing QGIS GUI a example of my code
  def __init__(self):
      code
      self.createBotton()
  def createButton(self):
      Here I create my button
      self.okbutton.clicked.connect(self.pressOkButton)
  def pressOkButton(self):
      here I call other methods
      self.methodA()
      self.methodB()

  def methodA(self):
      code
  def methodB(self):
      code
my question is--> how can i run 'pressOkButton' method in background? When i executed this method i can not ineract with QGIS GUI until finish method

Answer (score 1):

I have been using QTask in order to run heavy processes in the background.
The useful ressources I am using are these ones :

- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94477/how-to-use-threads-in-pyqgis-mainly-to-keep-ui-active
- https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/3004

You have to specifically create a new Class that inherits from `QgsTask` and call it in the `run()` method of your GUI Plugin.

In my case this is what I have :

```
class MyPlugin:
"""QGIS Plugin Implementation.
    ... __init__ method, tr method, initGui method, ...
"""
    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs the work after clicking 'OK' in the Plugin GUI"""
        task = MyTask('UserFriendlyTaskName', **props)
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask( task )


class MyTask(QgsTask):
    def __init__(self, task_name, **props):
        QgsTask.__init__(self, desc)
        # do w/e with the props
    def run(self):
        # call your heavy processes
```

See this .gif below for the UI rendering in QGIS3, there is no freezing and I can still move on the map and edit data while the plugin is running.

[QGIS GUI Launch Background Process GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJelM.gif)

Hope this answer finds you in time !

Comment: How should it be done when several methods shall be inserted to MyTask(QgsTask) ?

Answer (score 0):

thanks you for your answer

what I would to do is run a method in background without freezing QGIS GUI
a example of my code

```
class Example:
  def __init__(self):
      code
      self.createBotton()

  def createButton(self):
      Here I create my button
      self.okbutton.clicked.connect(self.pressOkButton)

  def pressOkButton(self):
      here I call other methods
      self.methodA()
      self.methodB()

  def methodA(self):
      code
  def methodB(self):
      code
```

my question is--> how can i run 'pressOkButton' method in background? When i executed this method i can not ineract with QGIS GUI until finish method

NOTE:consider that it is a class that belongs to my plugin so this class is instantiated when starting the plugin